# Ruby on Rails - Paperclip - Limit amount of images uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Question: How can I limit the amount of images uploaded for the "Picture" class, which accepts images, using Paperclip?**

I have model where items has a one to many relationship with pictures, and pictures has a attached file image, as shown in this code:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  has_attached_file :images, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },

  validates_attachment_content_type :images, :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/, :message => 'file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)'
end
```

This is the Item class:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Everything in terms of uploading works perfectly. However, what can I do to modify the Picture model to only accept a maximum of 4 images uploaded? Also, is it possible to have a pop up to say "You can only upload a maximum of four images"?

What other information do you require from me? (Schema/Controller? I'm not too keen on uploading these given it would be a bit too big)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom validation method in `Item` model (so each item can have maximum 4 pictures)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :only_4_pictures

  def only_4_pictures
    errors.add(:pictures, "You can't upload more than 4 pictures") if pictures.length > 4
  end

end
```

That will prevent the object to being saved.

Then how to show a popup really depends on the code of the view, you'll have access to the object and the error using object.errors[:pictures].